# How do I embed perl script in gwan c script?

Tags: c, perl, g-wan

Below is my c script. I don't know why EXTERN.h and perl.h is not found so I'm doing the user defined linking below. If can solve this, please help too.

I'm trying to embed perl script in C. The file is hell.c, shorten from the hello.c file

Would love to run embedded perl script from c.

Error as below when trying to run gwan:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/perl.h:2424:0,
                 from /home/qryos/Downloads/gwan_linux64-bit/0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0/csp/hell.c:9:
/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/handy.h:108:0: warning: "bool" redefined
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/include/stdbool.h:33:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/perl.h:3427:0,
                 from /csp/hell.c:9:
/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/utf8.h:46:10: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'unsigned'
In file included from /csp/hell.c:9:0:
/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/perl.h:4205:10: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'char'
/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/perl.h:4207:10: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'char'
```

Actual Script

```
// ============================================================================
// C servlet sample for the G-WAN Web Application Server (http://trustleap.ch/)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// hello.c: just used with ab (ApacheBench) to benchmark a minimalist servlet
// ============================================================================
#include "gwan.h" // G-WAN exported functions
//#include <EXTERN.h>
//#include <perl.h>
#include "/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/perl.h"
#include "/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/EXTERN.h"

    static PerlInterpreter *my_perl;

/*
    int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
    {
        char *args[] = { NULL };
        PERL_SYS_INIT3(&argc,&argv,&env);
        my_perl = perl_alloc();
        perl_construct(my_perl);
        perl_parse(my_perl, NULL, argc, argv, NULL);
        PL_exit_flags |= PERL_EXIT_DESTRUCT_END;
        call_argv("showtime", G_DISCARD | G_NOARGS, args);
        perl_destruct(my_perl);
        perl_free(my_perl);
        PERL_SYS_TERM();
    }
*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[])
{
   static char msg[] = "Hello, ANSI C!";
   xbuf_ncat(get_reply(argv), msg, sizeof(msg) - 1);

/*
        //PERL_SYS_INIT3(&argc,&argv,&env);
        my_perl = perl_alloc();
        perl_construct(my_perl);
        perl_parse(my_perl, NULL, argc, argv, NULL);
        PL_exit_flags |= PERL_EXIT_DESTRUCT_END;
//        call_argv("showtime", G_DISCARD | G_NOARGS, args);
        perl_destruct(my_perl);
        perl_free(my_perl);
        PERL_SYS_TERM();
*/

   return 200; // return an HTTP code (200:'OK')
}
```

**UPDATE, Gil suggestion**

I've put in this

```
#pragma include "/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/"
#include <EXTERN.h>
#include <perl.h>
```

Error below:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: hell.c
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/perl.h:2424:0,
                 from /home/example/Downloads/gwan/0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0/csp/hell.c:9:
/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/handy.h:108:0: warning: "bool" redefined
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/include/stdbool.h:33:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/perl.h:4829:0,
                 from /csp/hell.c:9:
/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/proto.h:690:47: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'off64_t'
/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/proto.h:697:21: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Perl_do_sysseek'
/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/proto.h:702:21: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Perl_do_tell'
/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/proto.h:6019:21: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Perl_PerlIO_tell'
/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/proto.h:6020:53: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'off64_t'
/csp/hell.c:29:5: error: conflicting types for 'main'
/home/example/Downloads/gwan/include/gwan.h:36:13: note: previous declaration of 'main' was here
```

Answer (score 0):

You have compilation errors in the Perl C headers. You should start with this.

It looks like the main issue is missing definitions, look for Perl directory tree dependencies and add any missing directory with the G-WAN `#pragma include` directive:

```
#pragma include "/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/"
```

THEN, you will be able to use `#include <perl.h>`.

Keep in mind that G-WAN won't compile a program that fails to compile with GCC. So your first step is probably to make your Perl script embedding work as a stand-alone program... and then try to integrate it with G-WAN.

Comment: #pragma include "/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/" doesnt work. i have to make it #pragma include "/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/"
but the error is still there. pls see update. thanks

Comment: tldr; I would like to understand how to properly link files with example installation tutorial for hiredis and ssdb.io on fresh installation of ubuntu or centos from scratch. my program works as standalone program. i'm proficient in php and perl but after a week of playing with g-wan, i still can't write a decent program on it. mostly because of the linking above. i would like to use ssdb.io in cpp and hiredis for redis. can you do some tutorial on the proper library linking with examples? from scratch for ubuntu servers (first and then centos)?

Comment: I can code purely in php or perl but there's no necessity of using gwan for this then coz the underlying bottleneck / performance problem is still the language at the end of the day. If I can just get through properly getting this linking thing done, I'm sure I can start to contribute some example coding... this is really very difficult. the rationale is to use C or CPP with gwan and only them.

Comment: Would love to see some embedded perl in action on gwan C / cpp script (or embedded php in action)

Comment: Sorry I think what I'm asking for is docker ubuntu for g-wan that can run hiredis and ssdb as example. Thanks! Please dockerize it.

Comment: You should ask assistance from https://www.docker.com/ rather than from G-WAN then.